# C# Bass.dll read Radio-Stream Title + Artist?

Tags: c#, internet-radio, axwindowsmediaplayer, bass.dll

I currently woking on a Project, which can play radio-streams. These streams will be played with the axWindowsMediaPlayer Control. But how can I read the stream title + artist?

Greetings from germany, Max

Answer (score 0):

from the docs...

```
char *BASS_ChannelGetTags(
DWORD handle,
DWORD tags)
```

Would be the bit in bass.

```
 // get a pointer to the 1st tag
char *icytags=BASS_ChannelGetTags(channel, BASS_TAG_ICY);
    if (icytags)
       while (*icytags) {
    printf("%s\n", icytags); // display the tag
    comments+=strlen(icytags)+1; // move on to next tag
}
```

This is the code for the ogg comments, but with icytags replaced. I haven't tried it, but if you look here :
[The BASS Docs of BASS_ChannelGetTags](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_ChannelGetTags.html)

It might help. The other tags are other data structures, you would approach them differently.